# HttpUrlConnection get Method

Tags: httpurlconnection

I am stuck at the `HttpUrlConnection` class, I wrote a simple application that sends SMS over requesting `GET` method supplied by a third party server.

The problem is that the same code runs great in Java, but not in Android. 
Can you help me understand why the `GET` request doesn't work?

```
package com.example.ihsanemre.samplenetwork;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UTFDataFormatException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "HttpExample";
    private EditText urlText;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        urlText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myUrl);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myClickHandler();
            }
        });
    }

    // When user clicks button, calls AsyncTask.
    // Before attempting to fetch the URL, makes sure that there is a network connection.
    public void myClickHandler() {
        // Gets the URL from the UI's text field.
        String stringUrl = "http://api.iletimerkezi.com/v1/send-sms/get/?username=5072071416&password=emre1211&text=Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet&receipents=5300730230&sender=ILETI%20MRKZI";
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);
        } else {
            textView.setText("No network connection available.");
        }
    }

    // Uses AsyncTask to create a task away from the main UI thread. This task takes a
    // URL string and uses it to create an HttpUrlConnection. Once the connection
    // has been established, the AsyncTask downloads the contents of the webpage as
    // an InputStream. Finally, the InputStream is converted into a string, which is
    // displayed in the UI by the AsyncTask's onPostExecute method.
    private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            textView.setText(result);
        }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;
        // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
        // web page content.
        int len = 5000;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(false);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
            is = conn.getInputStream();

            // Convert the InputStream into a string
            String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
            return contentAsString;

            // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
            // finished using it.
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }
    public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[len];
        reader.read(buffer);
        return new String(buffer);
    }
}
```

The Server always send me Http:200 ok but variables cannot be inserted to database

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: i mean everytime i  run the program even in real devices not emulator ,the variables can not be posted ,i checked the phpmyadmin but when i copy and paste the url to chrome ,it works great is anything wrong the above code@hgoebl

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. Maybe adding some `Log.d()` calls or some `try-catch` might help you where the program hangs or what is going wrong. We cannot help you without this information. The code doesn't look bad, but it's a lot easier to help when we know what goes wrong. Edit your question and don't add comments.